# How link particular part of svg file ?

Tags: html, xml, svg

I created svg file in adobe illustrator. its map of building showing rooms. now i want, if user click on say 137 room number he/she goes to google.com.(different room numbers take to different link)
[image]

map image look like this!
[Here is source code of svg](http://visitnearn.com/first_floor.svg)

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#Links:

```
<a xlink:href="http://example.com/room/137">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 233.75 40.875)" class="st7 st8 st9">137</text>
</a>
```